# jQuery: Is there a way to make this shorter and more elegant?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <img id="first"  class="images" src="img/nike.jpg" />
        <img  id ="second" class = "images" src="img/golden.jpg" />
        <img id = "third" class ="images" src ="img/a.jpg" />
        <img id = "fourth" class="images" src="img/God__s_Canvas_by_Delacorr.jpg" />
    </div>
```

I want to wrap each img with `<a name = n>` dynamically. So my solution was to do this:

```
$(".images").wrap('<a></a>')
$("#wrapper a").each(function(n) {
            $(this).attr('name', n);
        })
```

Is it possible to chain the 2 statements into 1 statement? I know that jQuery is particularly do elegant chaining so I think it's definitely possible. I just don't know how to yet.

Comment: Man... I love jQuery's chaining capabilities. It's hard to tell which is best since your solution as well as all the answers are perfectly legitimate and good solutions. I would give Dan the elegance award but it's hard to say which of the three current solutions is BEST. Elegant-looking doesn't always mean it is better-performing. I want to say that Dan's would perform the best two as the least amount of looping needs to take place in order for the task to be accomplished. Good stuff guys. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't exactly the same because it doesn't wrap .images outside of #wrapper, but it's close. It creates the  in the loop and immediately applies the attribute.

```
$('#wrapper img').each(function(n) { 
    $(this).wrap($('<a></a>').attr('name', n));
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. jQuery rocks! +1

Answer (score 3):

this might work...

```
$(".images").wrap('<a></a>').parent().each(function(n) {$(this).attr('name', n);});
```

Comment: Thanks!! I never thought of parent(). I never thought it was just this simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could, because you are referencing two separate collections of objects. The $() will return an array of matched items. In the case of your first implementation, you're pulling each image with a class of 'image' and wrapping them with the anchor tags. With your second implementation you're pulling all of the anchor tag elements within your 'wrapper' div, and applying the name attribute. These are two distinctly different collections, with the second one not even being available until after you've completed the first statement.

Now, Dan's implementation above might do the trick. Not the chaining you were looking for, but seems on the money.